# C# EF + Repository + UnitOfWorkk pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question about architecture , this is my scenario, I am building a layered solution using EF , so I did Repositories for my entities and UnitOfWork to manage my repositories is perfect I put control methods and transaction works , my bussiness entity consumes the unit of work , and I get to work with my business rules , but I have a problem, for example , there is a method I need to use two methods of business to avoid code repetition and work in the same transaction How can I do this ?

Bussiness methods below:

```
    public void LinkCard(int cardId, long pin) 
    {
        if (cardId < 1 || pin < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameters!");

        using (UnitOfWorkBol uowb = new UnitOfWorkBol(Log))
        {
            try
            {
                Card card;
                bool success = true;
                Pin pinResult;

                if(!Validator.UseRelesead(cardId, out card, uowb))
                    throw new CardException("La tarjeta no liberado para su uso!");

                pinResult = uowb.RepositoryPin.LoadPinByPin(pin);

                if(!Validator.UseRelesead(pinResult))
                    throw new CardException("La cuenta no está aprobado para su uso!");

                //se não existir cadastra o novo cartão caso contrário só vincula
                if (card == null)
                {
                    card = new Card
                            {
                                CARD_ID = cardId,
                                DISABLED = false,
                                pin = pinResult
                            };

                    success = uowb.GetBaseRepository<Card>().Add(card);
                }
                else 
                { 
                    card.pin = pinResult;
                    success = uowb.RepositoryCard.Update(card);
                }

                if (success)
                    uowb.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.MostraMensagem(LogClass.MsgType.Error, 0, "LinkCard()" + ": " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }    
    }

    public void CancelCard(int cardId, int reasonId, long Epin) 
    {
        if (cardId < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameter", "cardId");

        using(UnitOfWorkBol uowb = new UnitOfWorkBol(Log))
        {
            try
            {

                if (Validator.IsCancelled(cardId, uowb))
                    throw new CardException("La tarjeta ya se cancela!");

                Card card = uowb.GetBaseRepository<Card>().LoadById<int>(cardId);

                if (card == null)
                    throw new CardException("Tarjeta no encontrada!");

                //adiciona o cartão na tabela de cancelamento e o desativa
                CancelCard cancel = new CancelCard()
                {
                    card = card,
                    cashier_hist = uowb.RepositoryCashierHist.LoadCurrentCashierHist(Epin),
                    DATE = DateTime.Now,
                    reason_of_cancel = uowb.GetBaseRepository<ReasonOfCancel>().LoadById<int>(reasonId)
                };

                card.DISABLED = true;
                card.pin = null;

                bool success = uowb.GetBaseRepository<CancelCard>().Add(cancel);

                if (success)
                    success = uowb.GetBaseRepository<Card>().Update(card);

                if (success)
                    uowb.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.MostraMensagem(LogClass.MsgType.Error, 0, "CancelCard()" + ": " + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

i need call these methods in one on the transaction, thanks!

guys, i used transactionScope and works fine, but i dont like this solution because i am opening many transactions the code below:

```
   public void CancelAndLinkCard(CancelAndTransferDTO dto) 
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) 
        {
            CancelCard(dto.OldCardId, dto.ReasonId, dto.Epin);
            LinkCard(dto.NewCardId, dto.Pin);
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
```

maybe to use a facade pattern and the view access the facade and this to control the transaction is better but i dont know i need help thanks by replies

Comment: Do you mean that you want a `LinkCard()` and a `CancelCard()` in one transaction?

Comment: And which version(s)? EF6 has a new API for Transactions.

Comment: EF 4, in one transaction, it would be if LinkCard get trouble roolback all transaction or CancelCard(), note  the saveChanges() at the end of the both, this commit my transaction

Comment: "so I did Repositories" This word "so" intrigues me. It's not obvious at all to bury `DbContext`s and `DbSet`s under a clunky layer of units of work and repositories. I've seen so many examples of this: first people tie their hands behind their backs and then ask StackOverflow how to scratch their foreheads. The main trouble here is that your unit of work is not a unit: you need two units to execute one *real* unit of work. Re-think your architecture. It stands in your way more than it helps you.

Comment: basically my repositories just contain methods that access the database generics and specifics querys

Comment: Gert Arnold basically my repositories only contain methods that access the database , generic details and queries , and others like , add, delete and update my UnitOfWork contains references these repositories and commit methods as generally I follow the examples in the msdn , my problem is that my view , there is a button for example that just cancels card and other just assume a new card and another that execute both rules , if something is wrong with my concept , please show me a correct example thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of these methods are in the same class you could assign the dbContext to a private property and use it instead of creating a new dbContext for each of the methods (And take out your Using statements because otherwise it will dispose of the context when it leaves them).

However, I agree with Gert above - the structure of your solution is what is making this hard for you. DbContext IS a Unit of Work repository and should be treated as such. When we make repositories of repositories it just becomes turtles all the way down and madness comes of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are disposing of the context in both methods, I really don't see a way to make it happen. I will probably just write another method that does both things.

Answer (score 0):

i understand your point of view, so how i said to Gert if you have a good example it would be a good help, maybe these parts of add, delete they should be inside the repository, this way i can reuse.